# receiving unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, Create Directory

Tags: php

I tried to create folder directory name "code", and I want to save it to "status.txt".

This is my code problem with received the  unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING.

```
if(is_writeable($newdir . "/status.txt")) {
    if (fwrite($statusTxt, $statusCode . "," . $status . "," . $share . "," . $date . "," . $permission "\n")){
}
```

Is this way is correct to create a directory and save it to status.txt?
Below is the rest of the code.

Thank you so much, and appreciate for the help.

```
$newdir = "../../data/code";
umask(0007);
if(!file_exists($newdir))
{
    mkdir($newdir, 02770);
$statusTxt = fopen($newdir. "/status.txt", "a");
}
if(is_writeable($newdir . "/status.txt")) {
    if (fwrite($statusTxt, $statusCode . "," . $status . "," . $share . "," . $date . "," . $permission "\n")){
}
    echo "<p>Your form has succesfully been submit!</p>";
}
fclose($statusTxt);
}
```

Comment: You're missing a `.` before the final `\n` on the fwrite call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
if(is_writeable($newdir . "/status.txt")) {
    if (fwrite($statusTxt, $statusCode . 
             "," . $status . "," . $share . "," . 
             $date . "," . $permission  . "\n"))
                                     ^^^^^^  
...
```

Also, you may want to swap `\n` out for the constant `PHP_EOL`.

Comment: Thank you, this little mistake is annoying, thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

Your last concatenation, for the `"\n"`, is missing the `.` before it. The error basically means that you have a string where it's not expected.

Comment: thank you, thank you, this little mistake is annoying.